# What happens when I configure my USB hard drive for Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

What happens when I configure my USB drive for the Xbox 360?

Once it is configured, will I be able to use it like normally on my laptop/other computers? Will I be able to see files from the Xbox (such as saved games) on the USB drive when it's plugged into a PC?

Comment: You can divide the stick into multiple partitions. One for Xbox and one for PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off: YES, formatting a USB Drive for use with an Xbox ***will erase all files*** that are currently on the USB drive.

In order for the Xbox to format a USB drive for use, the USB drive must go through some checks on performance and available space (minimum of 1GB required). Once that's done you can set how much space you want reserved on the drive to be used by the Xbox.

Viewing these files on a PC is ***not officially supported by Xbox***, so to be able to view these files on a PC you must download a third-party software such as [MODIO](http://www.game-tuts.com/community/modio.php). Once installed you can use that to browse the USB drive and look at the Xbox files.

Note that Xbox only supports a max 32GB of space on USB drives. This can be either a single 32GB drive or 2 16GB drives.

[Step-by-step directions](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive) on how to format your drive, along with some additional info.

Comment: As you point out viewing the files on a HDD that was connected to an XBOX 360 is not supported.  Even if you do view the contents of the drive it would be multiple large files ( 4GB+ ) which are basically archive files ( i.e. 001, 002, 003, 004, ... ).  Any profile data ( save files, video content, ect ) would be split among those files.

Comment: Large files shouldn't be on there unless you specifically move them yourself. Especially since you only need 1GB allocated to the Xbox which won't fit the archive files you mention. I moved over a few ~60KB save files yesterday with no problem. The only files that appear are ones you move so it's not hard to navigate, especially using the MODIO program.

Comment: If you use a drive larger than 32GB, only 32GB will be usable. So don't get something bigger expecting more.